# Php transform file from url to blob to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, blob

I am trying to convert an image from an url to a blob file which can be used in javascript but I fail, how can I do this or is this even possible:

So far I have done this:

```
    // $request->location is the url to the file in this case an image
    $img = file_get_contents($request->location);

    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request->location);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    $img = curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $img;
```

I want to return that blob and append it to my FileReader object on my client / javascript side.

Comment: Why are you loading the image twice? And what seems to be the problem exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: The constructor for a Blob is quite simple, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Syntax - so what exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Just using [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) should give you the raw contents of the image. There is no need to do another curl request.

```
return file_get_contents($request->location);
```

Comment: The location can be a pdf aswell would that work too, because I want to append that blob in javascript to my Filereader object

Comment: Yes, `file_get_contents` will load any file regardless of its type.

Comment: Do you have an example to put that into a FileReader image object?
Currently it looks like this: `array(5) { ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["file"]=> string(346734) "ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛCÿÂQ°"ÿÄÿÄÌEN"­@ê³J©Î9¯.ÀJ±É)»I ËuÙYÔeÞfÊ°5önù¬9dô¬ú  -t(-+\õí<(÷"çöÈÑøf¬R'­¨Ü` but it should pass an object

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used the "**image-to-blob**" javascript library? Maybe it can be tried.
Please check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-blob).

Or you can also try using "**JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob**", for more details check [here](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob).

I once tried to convert the image url to base64 using javascript, if you are interested I can share the code.